# Gulp и Sass, автопереписывание url'ов

Tags: gulp, sass

Как автопереписывать в gulp url'ы изображений и т.д. Чтобы на продакшн версии всё стояло как надо.

Comment: Могу дать ссылку на сборщик проектов с такой реализацией

Comment: Т.е. плагина такого нет, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @Denisoed Если это ваш проект (имеете отношение) это будет нужно явно сказать при постинге ссылок, иначе можно нарваться за санкции за рекламу.

Comment: @AK, можно ссылки на правила или обсуждения на Мете, где говорилось бы о санкциях за постинг ссылок? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Это в чате было обсуждение первой блокировки Valdizar: постил свою библиотеку не раскрывая принадлежность к своему авторству. Какими конкретно правилами/обсуждениями на мете это регламентировалось -- не помню, чтобы приводились конкретные ссылки.

Comment: @AK, мне неизвестна история конфликта с Valdizar. Однако возможно Valdizar постил не в тему либо его сообщения носили рекламный характер. Однако с санкциями *только* за то, что автор не раскрывает свою причастность к программному продукту, не согласен. Если использование его библиотеки помогало в решении задач, а сообщения были написаны в нейтральном стиле, не вижу повода для санкций. Возможно, данный вопрос следует обсудить на Мете. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных скорее всего, речь [вот об этом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу автора, причем тут ваши непонятные беседы про санкции, манкции, у Обамы научились что ли? Если есть полезные ссылки по данной теме почему бы их дать нуждающимся.... А вопросах авторства или причастности пусть  беспокоится автор...